# Average Kolmogorov complexity of an integer factorization

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, kolmogorov-complexity

The other day I discovered the [Hardy-Ramanujan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Ramanujan_theorem), which suggested to me that the Kolmogorov complexity of any factorization of some $n$, given $n$, is negligible, a claim I am looking to verify.  I.e., because there are few prime factors, any partition thereof can be described efficiently.

The theorem states that the number of prime factors with multiplicity,  $\Omega(n)$, takes the expected value
$$ E[\Omega(n)] = \ln \ln n $$
(if the `$\log$' in the original is the natural logarithm).

Assume that you are given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and know that $\exists x_1,\ldots,x_k. \prod_{i=1}^k x_i = n$.  The number of ways of distributing the $\Omega(n)$ prime factors among $k$ distinct composite factors is no more than $k^{\Omega(n)}$, describable in $\approx \Omega(n) \lg k$ bits.  Some ways of summarizing this are as follows:
$$ K(x_{1\ldots k} \mid n, k) \le \Omega(n)\cdot\lg k + O(1) $$
$$ E[K(x_{1\ldots k} \mid n, k)] = \ln\ln n\cdot \lg k + O(1) $$
$$ E[K(x_{1\ldots k} \mid n, k)] \le \lg\lg n\cdot \lg k + O(1) $$
$$ E[K(x_{1\ldots k} \mid n)] \le K(k) + \lg\lg n\cdot \lg k + O(1) $$
If we assume that $k \le \Omega(n)$:
$$ E[K(x_{1\ldots k} \mid n, k)] \le \lg\lg n\cdot \lg\lg\lg n + O(1) $$

From this I conclude that, in general, $K(n, x_{1\ldots k} ) \sim K(n)$.

Is this correct?